# How best to create a HMI display panel (user-customised interface) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, form-designer

I need to improve a screen in our Application that presents an HMI ([Human Machine Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface)) display embedded in our Delphi code. This screen provides our customer with the ability to perform a range of actions (run test, product report etc) and to expose and view key named data values. This customisation is required because our Application controls machinery that might be operated by a range of skill levels from simple operator (may not speak English and must have very limited control) through to a power user who wishes to 'see everything' and have max control.

Some years back I created a solution based on an embedded HTML viewer (Turbopower's as it was then) and TPageProducer to dynamically tweak an HTML template (that the user could customise) and which would display a simple set of controls and data tables. This works fine but is slow to edit (you have to tweak the template and look-see the effect) and I'm sure there are better ways now.

What I need is similiar to a Delphi form that can be customised at runtime. I need: buttons, labels and edits. Editable shapes and arrows are desireable as are fixed images over which controls and text can be laid. The layout should be saveable (like a DFM file) and text labels should be of two types - fixed text and those which update to display key values on an update notification (like a DB control would). The final layout should zoom its scale to fit a resizable layout.

This question is about the best tool for the job and I'm not coming into this totally cold, I've experimented with [Greatis Form Designer](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/formdes/) and obtained a working solution but before I commit, I would apprecaite comments about whether a report tool (with built-in report editor) would be possible / useable / better since a print dump feature would also be useful. (Fast Reports? Quick Report etc?). Note though that this is a display requirement primarily. Comments re newer embedded HTML solutions would also be welcome as would anything to ensure max future-proofing of the layout format.

Any solution should be useable in Dephi 7 (for now!) and does not need to be unicode as long as there is a migration path to this for newer Delphi's.

Any other comments or observations would be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit ironic that the 'Greatis Form Designer' isn't gratis.

Comment: I've been playing with a form designing at runtime some time ago and [TSizeCtrl](http://angusj.com/delphi/sizectrl.zip) was enough for me to manipulate with controls. I've created my own component palette so I can add exactly what I need there. A little problem was with loading a form from file. Even if you can simply save the form into a *.dfm file at runtime it's not so easy to build it back from the file. For my purposes I finally used my own file format where I'm saving again just what I need (size, position, data source etc.)

Comment: I have done a lot of HMI work in my day, and I found that letting the end user customize our displays ended up as a support nightmare. Click the blue Options button. Oh you removed it? Oh great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked first at the free JVCL stuff?  There's a JvInspector (RTTI component property inspector, just like Delphi property inspector), and a form designer, and so on. You could roll your own solution based on these, and even use JvInterpreter for some scripting capability.

Secondly, if you can support ANY control that you have, in your designer, and you need some HMI specific stuff, check out IOCOMP:  http://www.iocomp.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. The iocomp stuff looks rather snazzy, too.

Answer (score 0):

[TMS Scripter Studio Pro](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudiopro.asp) provides a Delphi-like IDE and form designer with scripting, but it maybe overkill for your requirements.

Comment: I just tried it, and it is very buggy. For one thing, my Swedish keyboard layout doesn't work with the program (but hey -- everyone lives in the US, don't they?). I also tried to work a bit in the IDE, and encountered a lot of flickering and bugs. I don't recommend this one.